# bing wallpapers

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, live, bing

I want to change my app background randomly, and I know that Bing has great collection of backgrounds.
Is there any API that contains the bing wallpapers, and lets me download them with some kind of API like rss, or something similar? I want a wide collection, and not just to download the daily one

Comment: Bing's images are copyrighted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download the daily bing image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084745/how-to-download-the-daily-bing-image)

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about bing but, You can use flickr API [Flicker](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2008/11/12/on-ui-quality-the-little-things-client-side-image-resizing/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check **Bing Homepage Gallery** (http://www.bing.com/gallery/), which is the official website about wallpapers on Bing Homepage.

And you can crawl/parse this website to download all the images. For example, URL of thumbnail for the wallpaper of Mar 24, 2017 is --

```
http://az619519.vo.msecnd.net/files/GrebesChick_EN-US11292928738_320x180.jpg
```

Its download version is --

```
http://az608707.vo.msecnd.net/files/GrebesChick_EN-US11292928738_1920x1200.jpg
```

So the pattern is `http://az608707.vo.msecnd.net/files/{}_1920x1200.jpg`, and works for the rest images on that page.

Comment: This question is 8 years old, so I hope the user has solved their problem. Also, "it's not hard" isn't an answer to a question.

Comment: Not 8 years old, it's 5. He asked for *"API like rss, or something similar"* --- IMHO, a webpage contains all the image is not far from any feed. Thanks for your kind reminder, and I won't say *"it's not hard"* next time.

Comment: Sorry, the 8 was me missing the 5 key lol. There's nothing wrong with saying `It's not hard` in itself. You previous version basically just said only that. **Anyway, looks very nice now. Have 10 points :)**, which will unlock commenting for you.

Comment: You got me:) Thanks for your help!