# How to download the daily bing image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have seen several applications that allow the user to download the daily bing images and use them on their phones for various purposes. How are these apps doing this? I could not find any information regarding the steps to accomplish this, although my application could really use some sprucing up on my page background.

Comment: The daily bing images are typically copyrighted, with may be a problem

Answer (score 1):

[Here is Bing's dynamic feed](http://themeserver.microsoft.com/default.aspx?p=Bing&c=Desktop&m=en-US) for  the desktop. I'm not sure where the one for the web is.

Comment: Would I call that in a service reference in my Wp7 app? and, if so, how do I set it up from there?

Comment: It's just an XML document, you can handle it anyway you want. I'll see if I can come up with an example using the framework.